# wp_nav_menu() seems to ignore my given parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's how my header code along with our fateful menu looks like

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="top">
<header role="banner">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="logo"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
    <p class="desc">
        <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
    </p>
    <nav role="navigation" class="ink-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => '',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => 'wrtwert',
'container_id'    => 'sdfgdsfgsfg',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => 'ffffff',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s someclasssss">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => ''    )); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</header>
```

And here is the only output i ever get http://puu.sh/5cGNr.png. They only parameter that seems to work is the menu class, so if i change that i get a different output but it's not even targeting the class that it should. I saw this was asked time and again and i looked into the like 10 threads about this, tried the said solutions but to no avail. What i want to do is give my ul list a class, and i'd also like to know how the others can be changed if i need to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, a pretty stupid omission by my part but still, somebody might do the same. My problem was i had no registered menus. I omitted that because my themes were actually showing my pages in the navigation bar so i thought it was there. Quite strange.